# How do I find the right resistor for an LED panel?

Tags: led, resistors, multimeter

I purchased one of [these cheap LED panels](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076HRDKLT) to light a room.  One review suggested that it's important to put a resistor on it, to keep it from frying itself.  But, he didn't list what resistor to use.

I've searched around and found a lot of discussions of resistors for individual LEDs.  But, I haven't stumbled onto the right page for this situation.

I have a UNI-T multimeter.  I saw "[Easy way to figure out a LED's Vf in order to pick an appropriate resistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/328424/resistor-after-leds-is-this-right,%20but%20putting%20the)", but putting my multimeter into what I think is diode mode stayed stuck at 0L.  (I was careful about polarity.)

This is my first encounter with "forward voltage" so, it's a bit overwhelming.

Thanks.

----- Edit

I understand that you can't give me a definitive answer.  But, does anyone have a Scientific Wild Ass Guess?  Something along the lines of, probably higher than this.  I'd be surprised if higher than that.  And, likely around here?  Just a ballpark number that has a reasonable chance of being safe?

And, I haven't ever bought something like this.  A suggestion or two on a source would help me out.

I appreciate everyone's input.  I understand that not having a data sheet makes this a pain.  But, this is just a DYI thing, and they're *so* inexpensive that it's hard for me to pass them up.

Comment: That you get 0L is probably because your multimeter's power rail is less than the forward voltage, see my related question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/431009/diode-meter-of-my-dmm-does-work-for-red-leds-but-not-for-white-leds

Comment: that looks like as assembler lamp module designed for direct connectio to 12-14VDC/

Comment: I doubt it needs any resistor.  It probably contains current limiting resistors already or, more likely, a constant current circuit.

Answer (score 4):

The ad (not the same thing as a datasheet) tells you that it is 12 V and 70 W. From this we can work out that at 12 V you will need a 70 / 12 = 6 A, 12 V power supply. The current limiting resistors are, hopefully, built in.

No datasheet? No sale!

Comment: Yes, I purchased an appropriate power supply, and I've mounted a heat sink to it.  I've tested it for a few seconds.  Very bright.  I think it's going to work well where I want to use it.  I just need to get the resistor figured out, so I don't kill it quickly.

It's very low profile, so I can't see where they would include a resistor within the package.

Comment: The device says "Plug and Play" which is why T says the resistors are hopefully built in.  A power LED device can't be "Plug and Play" if it doesn't have current control.  Unfortunately whatever control circuit/resistors are on the device are obscured by the lens.  In one of the images it has a device labelled "LED Controller" inline, so if that isn't included in your module, and it is itself the current control, you may need to get a driver.

Comment: That controller doesn't come with it.  The lens is translucent enough that I can see the individual LEDs.  I can see that there is no other circuitry nestled in.

They're only $10.  I should probably just rip one apart and see how they're connected and if there's anything else there.